# Why is this a smoothed indicator function?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, derivatives

I am reading some notes and the author is claiming the following. Let $c(x,y)$ be a real function.

Let $g(u,v)$ be a functional defined on $L^1 (\mathbb R)\times L^1(\mathbb R)$ such that it takes values $0$ if $u(x)+v(y)\leq c(x,y)$ for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ or $+\infty$ otherwise.

He defines a smoothed approximation of this functional by

$$\epsilon\log \int_{\mathbb R^2} e^{\frac{u(x) +v(y) - c(x,y)}{\epsilon}} dx dy, \quad \epsilon >0$$

How is this a smoothed approximation of $g$ ? What mollifier was used ? By smoothed, I would imagine that it means that this new version has Fréchet derivatives ? How to show that ?

Comment: Are you missing some restrictions on $c$ here? Otherwise, I think $c$ can be chosen to make the exponential expression un-integrable.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The author is not so clear about that, so I guess $c$ is such that this integral exists.